# How to save a image after using imshowpair function

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

Hi I am trying to save/display an image after using it in `imshowpair` function. The following code doesn't work. Does anyone know how I can achieve what I want?

```
final = imshowpair(img1, img2, 'montage');
imshow(final);              // -> not working
imwrite(final,'path.....'); // -> also not working
```

Comment: Doesn't it appear automatically? It should, according to the documentation. (I don't have the necessary toolbox. What do you get if you type `whos final`?

Comment: You are right,It is appearing automatically, but my aim is to use that combined image to other operation hence I need to save it. but its thowing an error in that case

Comment: Name       Size            Bytes  Class                              Attributes

  final      1x1                60  matlab.graphics.primitive.Image

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do, to be able to save an image in the same way that `imshowpair` displays it:

```
I = imread('peppers.png'); % Dummy image.
I2 = imfilter(I, ones(3,3)); % Dummy image 2.
imshowpair(I, I2, 'montage'); 
I3 = [I, I2]; % This line makes a montage out of the two images.
imshow(I3) % This is effectively what imshowpair displays.
imwrite(I3, 'myfile.png'); % Save I3 to a file.
```

Comment: Thank you, I have got my desired output :)